# How to extract Json object strings separated by specific pattern?

Tags: c++, regex, qt

So the question is quite straightforward. After a couple of hours browsing threads about regex i still can't come up with one that would handle a string as stated in the code section.

Here are some of the regular expressions I tried (without escaping the backslash for the sake of reading) :

```
/\d+({.*?})(?:(|\d+|$|))/;
/\d+({.+})(?:(|\d+|$|))/;
/\d+({.*?})(?:(|\d+|\B|))/;
/\d+({.+})(?:(|\d+|\B|))/;
/\d+({.*?})(?:(|\d+|))/;
/\d+({.+})\d+/;
/\d+({.*?})\d+/;
```

This one is the closest i got to what i except:

```
/\d+({.*?})\d+|\d+({.*?})/
```

```cpp
QString haystack = "5:4{"type":"someType","data":{"subJson":123}}"\
                       "9406:22{"type":"SomeOtherType","data":{"subJson":648,"data":{"subSubJson":25}}}"\
                       "125:10{"last":79}";     // The quotes are obviously escaped but reading sake...

QRegularExpression re = QRegularExpression("\\d+({.*?})\\d+|\\d+({.*?})");
QRegularExpressionMatchIterator i = re.globalMatch(haystack);

QStringList matches;
while (i.hasNext()) {
    QRegularExpressionMatch match = i.next();
    QString result = match.captured(1); // Group match
    matches << result;
}

qDebug() << matches;
```

What I expect:

```
"{"type":"someType","data":{"subJson":123}}"
"{"type":"SomeOtherType","data":{"subJson":648,"data":{"subSubJson":25}}}"
"{"last":79}"
```

What I actually get:

```
"{"type":"someType","data":{"subJson":123}}"
"{"type":"SomeOtherType","data":{"subJson":648,"data":{"subSubJson":25}}}"
"" //The last one wasn't matched
```

BUT the with the full match I get this:

```
"4{"type":"someType","data":{"subJson":123}}9406"
"22{"type":"SomeOtherType","data":{"subJson":648,"data":{"subSubJson":25}}}125"
"10{"last":79}"
```

Comment: What is the "specific pattern" in the separator?

Comment: For now i'm expecting a pattern of numbers separated by a colon ###:###. The haystack in the code section show an example.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was:

```
/\d+({.*?})(?:\d+|$)/
```

First a check for prepending digits with '\d+', then a group match for everything between curly braces without being greedy thus the '({.*?})', and finally an excluded group match '?:' will stop the preivous group match at either a set of digits '\d+' or the end of word '$', '(?:\d+|$)'

Comment: A good answer shouldn't just contain code, it should explain what was wrong in the question and how the solution fixes it.